# Subtract month and day mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to subtract 1 month and 4 days with mysql, I saw the command
`DATE_ADD (NOW (), - 1 MONTH)` perfect for 1 month but for 1 month and 4 days, using 31 days is not valid for every month that some bring 30, 29, 28. I can not add 31 + 4, 30 + 4, etc.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

using [`DATE_SUB` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)
 like :

```
DATE_SUB((DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL -1 MONTH), INTERVAL -4 DAY)
```

Answer (score 17):

Keep it simple:

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 4 DAY;
```

or

```
SELECT '2014-03-27' - INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 4 DAY;
```

or if you like to preserve the current time:

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH - INTERVAL 4 DAY;
```

(Tested on MySQL 5.1.73 and newer)

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL - 1 MONTH + INTERVAL - 4 DAY;`
or
`SELECT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL - 1 MONTH + INTERVAL - 4 DAY;`