# How to subtract one to the month of a date format in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Assuming I have a select statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), wedding, DATE_FORMAT(weddate, '%y %m %d') FROM weddingtable
```

I want to make it such that I could subtract 1 from the month it would return:
for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), wedding, DATE_FORMAT(weddate, '%y %m-1 %d') FROM weddingtable
```

It appears to just append "-1" to the month integer instead of actually subtracting one from the month. How do I accomplish this? (in other words, where it would normally return 5 in place of %m, it would return 4, etc.)

Note: For January, I would expect in place of %m, it would be "0".

Comment: what if it's 1/1/2013? just subtracting the month is not enough. you need to take the entire date and subtract 1 month out of it, then format it.

Comment: Doesn't MYSQL automatically understand the year changed?

Comment: What if its January? I expect the output for %m to be "0" as opposed to thinking that it is December of a previous year and using "12" instead.

Comment: @Damascusi: Why on earth would anyone expect that?

Comment: @Damascusi Just run `select DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH);`. Internal calendar/date takes care of this issue with `DATE_SUB` using `INTERVAL`. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your solution can be derived from: [Subtract month and day mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568072/subtract-month-and-day-mysql)

e.g. `(DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

```
SELECT COUNT(*), wedding, DATE_SUB(weddate,INTERVAL 1 MONTH) FROM weddingtable
```

Comment: What if its January? I expect the output for %m to be "0".

Comment: `jan 2013` minus one month is `dec 2012`. there is no such thing as "month 0" in a valid date.

Comment: Just try: `select DATE_SUB(curdate(),INTERVAL 12 MONTH);` . You will see it says the current date 2012. MYSQL subtracts 12 months from current date.

Comment: I know Month "0" is not a valid date, but that is the point. I want a 0 there because that is how I want my date to be formatted based on my select query.

Answer (score 0):

To subtract one month from `weddate`, use `webdate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), wedding, DATE_FORMAT(weddate - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%y %m %d') FROM weddingtable
```

**Update:** To end up subtracting with month "0" after subtraction you can no longer use date arithmetic (because there is no month 0). Instead you'll have to pick apart the date with the `extract` function and concatenate the parts as a string:

```
concat_ws(' ', extract(year from webdate), 
               extract(month from webdate)-1, 
               extract(date from webdate))
```

Comment: Note that for January, I expect in place of %m to be 0.

Comment: In that case, see the update.