# MySQL Query for obtaining values from the beginning of the month

Tags: mysql

I am currently running the following MySQL query which returns the values from `column_1`, from the beginning of the day up until the current time.

*Current Query:*

```
SELECT column_1 FROM db.table_1 
WHERE TS >= CURDATE() AND TS < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ;
```

I need to modify this query on `column_1`, to return values from the previous month, but only returning the values from the previous month which are the same number of days after the start of the current month.

So, if today is February 8th, I would like to return the values from 00:00:00 on January 1 up until January 8th.  Or, if the day is March 25th, I want to return the values from 00:00:00 on February 1 until February 25th.

Thanks!

Comment: I think two questions is too broad.

Comment: I think you are looking for the DATE_SUB function.  Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946033/how-to-subtract-one-to-the-month-of-a-date-format-in-mysql