# I want to find the previous month's date for specific date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the previous month date for specific dates in SQL. For example: `6.21.19` has a previous month date of `5.21.19`.

I am just trying to get comps from this.

```
MONTH( curdate() ) -1
```

I need to return the previous month date.

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work? It is a syntax error ? Logic error?

Comment: @nicomp I am not able to get the previous date for each of the unique "current" dates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subtract month and day mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568072/subtract-month-and-day-mysql)

Comment: Are you sure this is for MySQL and not SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the board Arie. Judging from your question and responses, you need a range of dates and their prior month relations. The easiest way would be for all of the dates you need to look up to be in a table, then the answers provided so far would work. Since that doesn't appear to be the case, I'm guessing you are creating date ranges on the fly.

So lets assume you need exactly the data shown in your example, there are two parts to this, first you need to get a list of days that you want to look up, then you need to get the day in the prior month. There are lots of ways to get a sequence of days, but for simplicity I'll use a recursive CTE. Once I have the date range, I'll just select the dates and their prior month date as well.

```
with Date_CTE as (select cast('6/1/2019' as datetime) as repDate
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, repdate) as repDate
    from Date_CTE
    where repDate < '06/07/2019')
select repDate, dateadd(month, -1, repDate) as PriorDate
from Date_CTE
```

CTEs are helpful functions and you can get more details on them [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/), but it's worth noting there are many ways to do this. Hope this gets you pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT yourDateColumn, yourDateColumn-interval 1 month as prevMonthDate
```