# issue with sql query to fetch records before 1 month from current date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQLi and I have SQL structure like [This](https://www.screencast.com/t/kzpetDoSO) and I want all records which have expired date before 1 month

for that, I have tried

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    new_domain
WHERE
    DATEPART( m, expire_date ) = DATEPART( m, DATEADD( m, -1, getdate() ) )
    AND
    DATEPART( yyyy, expire_date ) = DATEPART( yyyy, DATEADD( m, -1, getdate() ) )
```

but with that, I have receive an error `#1305 - FUNCTION DATEPART does not exist`

can anybody help me with this

Comment: `DATEPART` is a T-SQL function (MS SQL Server), but looks like you're using MySQL or PostgreSQL, which have different date processing functions. Please update your question to state which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by before one month? Do you mean expires in 1 month and less or the opposite?

Comment: @TOH19 actually I want all data which have expire date before one month from the current date

Comment: @TOH19 but it is giving me data only last months, not before last month

Comment: Can you give an example please

Comment: @TOH19 I have data which have expire date from 2019 and when I hit this query it is giving data from 2020 3rd and 4th month

Comment: For example today is january 1st 2020, after lunching your query you want to select the rows that their expire dates are before december 1st 2019 right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209418/discussion-between-mnj-and-toh19).

Comment: @TOH19 For Example if today is 11th Mar 2020 and I want all data form 2019 to Feb

Comment: Lets continue in the chat room please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `CURDATE()` AND `INTERVAL` if I understand correctly your question: you are trying to select rows that expires in 1 month or less. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM new_domain
WHERE expire_date < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY;
```

Comment: @MNJ is this what you want?

Comment: wait let me check

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub). This type of question has already been [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568072/subtract-month-and-day-mysql) in StackOverflow. Please make sure you search before you ask.